# Why does the if - block >>>> if(!variable) <<<<< get executed when variable = 0?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, types, null, undefined

When I run this code the code in the if- block gets executed. My assumption was that **if** **!** *something*, it's either **null** or **undefinded**? Can anyone explain?

```
const num = 0;

if (!num) {
    console.log('Why on earth does this get printed');
}
```

Comment: `0` is a **falsy** value.  It is the only falsy number.

Comment: And !falsy equals true

Comment: And your code gets executed.

Comment: Thx! What's so wrong about this question??? I really don't see a reason to downvote this...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. When you implicitly convert a value to a boolean like that, it's converted according to the [*truthy* and *falsy* rules](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-toboolean). The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, and of course, `false`. (Also, interestingly, `document.all` on browsers.) All other values are *truthy*. So `if (!num)` will be true if `num` is `0`, because you've negated a falsy value (making it `true`).

If you just want to check for `null` and `undefined`, you can use `== undefined` or `num == null` (note: `==`, not `===`), which is true for both of them:

```js
if (num == null) {
    console.log("num is null or undefined");
}
```

The rules for `==` are such that both `null` and `undefined` are `== undefined` (and also `== null`), but nothing else is.

Or, perhaps more clearly:

```js
if (num === null || num === undefined)
    console.log("num is null or undefined");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- When you are using if statement, code in curly braces executes only if expression in round braces return true.
- You variable num has 0 assigned to it.
- Variable num would be  converted to false because 0 is assigned to it
- In Javascript, the exclamation mark (“!”) symbol, called a “bang,” is the logical “not” operator. Placed in front of a boolean value it will reverse the value, returning the opposite.
- Because of that you will get true inside curly braces
- This is a reason why your code executes